# Sort Dynamic Virtual Host Folders

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualization, host, dynamic

I'm trying to set up a dynamic virtual host for the first time with apache.
Is it possible for be to implement some sort of folder sorting system?

For example the first ten sites are in:
/Vhosts/1/
The next ten in :
/Vhosts/2/

And so on, in order to reduce indexing load and having 400 folders in one directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, have a look at the examples in the [mod_vhost_alias documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).